# canonical complete problems for $\Delta^P_n$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, alternating-hierarchy, polynomial-hierarchy

Finding whether or not a QBF can be satisfied is a canonical complete problem for both $\Sigma^P_n$ (start from $\exists$) and $\Pi^P_n$ (start from $\forall$). What is the canonical complete problem for $\Delta^P_n$?

Comment: Here we have [LaTeX support](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3/latex-math-support), so you may like to edit the question with dollar sign included. This makes it easier to read.

Comment: I added in the relevant symbols.

Comment: The following problem is complete for Δ_k P for obvious reasons: given a Turing machine M with the Σ_{k−1}-SAT oracle and a tally string 1^n, decide whether M accepts the empty input in time at most n.  Although I would call this problem a canonical complete problem for Δ_k P, I guess that you are looking for more natural problems.

Comment: There's a partial result when n = 2, which is the class $\mathsf{P^{NP}}$. This class has been discussed in MO, and the [answer by Ryan O'Donnell](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2218/characterize-pnp/2240#2240) is nice.

Comment: This is a nice question!

Comment: Thanks to Suresh Venkat and Hsien-Chich Chang 張顯之, I did not know that there was support for LaTeX. Very nice feature, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is a slightly more detailed version of my earlier comment, in response to the asker’s request by email.)

Since $\Delta_k^{\rm P} = {\rm P}^{\Sigma_{k-1}^{\rm P}}$ by definition, it should be clear that the following problem is $\Delta_k^{\rm P}$-complete: fix some $\Sigma_{k-1}^{\rm P}$-complete problem *L*.  (For example, *L* can be the special case of QBF where there are *k*−1 groups of consecutive quantifiers of the same kind and the first quantifier is existential (∃).)  Then given a Turing machine *M* with the *L* oracle, a string *x* and a tally string 1<sup>*t*</sup>, decide whether *M* accepts the input *x* in time at most *t*.  (A *tally string* simply means a string on the unary alphabet, that is, a string of the form 1<sup>*n*</sup>.)

I would not mind calling this problem a “canonical” $\Delta_k^{\rm P}$-complete problem, but this may not be what you are looking for.

In my earlier comment, I removed the input string *x* and assumed it was always the empty string.  This variant is also $\Delta_k^{\rm P}$-complete because you can hardwire the input string into a Turing machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For my needs, this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: @kvaruni: You are welcome.  By the way, you could post your request as a reply to my comment (by including “@Tsuyoshi” in a comment) instead of sending an email.  You can find a [(too) detailed explanation of the reply feature on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020).

Comment: @ Tsuyoshi Thanks for the help. This is my first question and first time ever that I have used this site, so bear with my. I am getting the hang of it :).