# What if a problem is both in $\Pi_2^p$ and $NP$-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes

If a problem $P$ belongs to both $\Pi_2^p$ and $NP$-hard (thanks to some reduction from a $NP$-complete problem) but not to $NP$, does it imply that $P$ is $\Pi_2^p$-complete?

If the answer is no, are there some problems with these properties which have not been shown to be $\Pi_2^p$-complete?

Comment: Please check [generalized Ladner’s theorem](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/799/generalized-ladners-theorem).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is "no".

In fact, in addition to the general argument pointed to by Tsuyoshi, there are a number of well-studied complexity classes which contain NP, but are contained in $\Pi_2^P$.

Two interesting containment chains are:

$NP \subseteq \Delta_2^P \subseteq S_2^P \subseteq \Sigma_2^P \cap \Pi_2^P \subseteq \Pi_2^P$

and

$NP \subseteq MA \subseteq BP \cdot NP = AM \subseteq \Pi_2^P$

To help clarify the letter soup, see Wikipedia's article on the [Arthur-Merlin protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur%E2%80%93Merlin_protocol) and [$S_2^P$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2P_%28complexity%29). There's also of course the [complexity zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo) for descriptions of these various classes.

Also take a look at [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/canonical-complete-problems-for-deltap-n) asking about canonical $\Delta_i^P$-complete problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers, I'll make sure to check them out.